# Memory debugger for c++ on mac?

Tags: c++, debugging

I'm developing a mac application in C++, and I'm having the following problem:

```
words(26222,0xa0b5c540) malloc: *** error for object 0x88dda04: 
incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after 
being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Anyway, I set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break but it doesn't tell me where I am modifying the memory.

Is there any memory debugger that gives me meaningful information about where am I messing up the memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/) is the standard open-source memory debugging tool. :-)

Comment: Great, I'm using it now. Do you know how to get valgrind to load debug symbols to show relevant information like line numbers? I'm building with xcode in debug mode, but I'm not sure what xcode does with the debug symbols...

Comment: I've found it. On the active target I selected DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT = dwarf-with-dsym